# retrofit print response success but cannot parse object

Tags: android, json, kotlin, generics, retrofit

Here are some function and class definition

retrofit interface

```
@POST("/Account/LogOn")
fun logOn(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

my custom interface

```
interface ApiCallback<T> {
    fun success(body: BaseResponse<T>)
    fun fail(message: String)
}
```

BaseResponse

```
class BaseResponse<T>(
    @SerializedName("success") var success: Boolean = false,
    @SerializedName("message") var message: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("data") var data: T? = null
)
```

```
fun logOn(request: LogonRequest, listener: ApiCallback<LogonResponse>) {
    getServiceModel().logOn(request.encode()).test(listener)
}
```

for some reason, request and response should encode and decode, so I have a generic decode function

```
fun <T> Call<ResponseBody>.test(listener: ApiCallback<T>) {
    enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(response.body()!!.string(), Base64.DEFAULT)
                val decodedString = String(decodedBytes)
                val baseMsType = object : TypeToken<BaseResponse<T>>() {}.type
                val decodeResponse = Gson().fromJson<BaseResponse<T>>(decodedString, baseMsType)

                listener.success(decodeResponse)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
        }

    })
}
```

so far is work and console print logger success
[image]

how I call it in ViewModel

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    val request = LogonRequest(userID = accountInfo.userID, userName = accountInfo.userName)
    MyService.Account.logOn(request, object : ApiCallback<LogonResponse> {
        override fun success(body: BaseMSResponse<LogonResponse>) {
            Log.d("TAG", " logOn body=" + body.data)
            Log.d("TAG", " logOn token=" + token)
        }
        override fun fail(message: String) {
        }
    })
}
```

`Log.d("TAG", " logOn body=" + body.data)` -> success print

2024-02-01 10:10:33.387 D/TAG:  logOn body={token=4F5663F1BBD91D90CDC7C1A9AFDCD72A69BC3198338C8120E5CE6B4395308E12}

`Log.d("TAG", " logOn token=" + body.data?.token)` -> crash
[image]

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.ms.aar.api.response.LogonResponse`

I have no idea why response body print success but cannot be parse to object.
Can anyone help me?